# How to convert iOS PencilKit binary data from CloudKit into a readable Image for Websites (PHP or JS)

Tags: javascript, php, ios, base64, cloudkit

Apple's PencilKit creates base64 data in a application/octa-stream format. But it seems to be impossible to convert these into an image for a Website. I wanne read out a public CloudKit database by PHP (that works) and get the by pencilKit drawn images on a Website as a png or any other transparent image file. What i receive is a octa-stream format, but dont have any idea how to convert this in a right way. Any ideas?

Thanks!
Robert

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to convert the PK octa-stream format to an image, this is impossible. The Workaround is to save in CloudKit a base64 image as a separate value too.